# Given coordinates of points, find all pairs of points that exist within a certain distance of each other?

Tags: algorithm

2 points are pairs if the distance between the two points are 0 <= D <= 1000. Given the 2D coordinates (floating point numbers) of 0 <= N <= 1000 stars, determine how many pairs there are.

I've seen this question a couple of times before but I forgot the implementation. I believe this had something to do with divide and conquer, where you split the plane by half and recurse on the two sides of the plane, but I'm very unsure of how that would work out.

No need for any code, just a general walkthrough of the solution for this type of problem would suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you might be thinking of is a [quad tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), the 2D case of a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). In a quad tree, you start with a bounding rectangle that encompasses all points. You insert all points into this base level.

From there, you divide the quad into either halves or quarters. You insert each point into the half or quarter into which it falls. You can further subdivide each half or quarter into smaller halves or quarters, inserting each point into the smaller areas they fall into.

To find all points within a distance of a given point, you simply find all quads in your tree that have any point within the given distance. Then you can test only points in those quads against your initial point.

This keeps you from doing the typical **n**<sup>2</sup> comparison of all points against one another.